# Move PmodOLED from JB to JA Header - 32MX4 (MPLAB X IDE)

Tags: microchip, mplab

I am new to programming for microcontrollers and my first task is to accept WiFi connections using the PmodWiFi add-on. I read that the default pin/port for the WiFi chip is the JB header on the 32MX4. The problem is that I currently have the PmodOLED add-on installed in the JB header, so I want to move it to the JA header. In `PmodOLED.h` (which I have imported into my library), I changed the following lines to correspond to the ports in the JA header instead of the JB header:

```
#define prtSelect   IOPORT_G 
#define prtDataCmd  IOPORT_B 
#define prtReset    IOPORT_D 
#define prtVbatCtrl IOPORT_D 
#define prtVddCtrl  IOPORT_B 

#define bitSelect   BIT_9 
#define bitDataCmd  BIT_15 
#define bitReset    BIT_5 
#define bitVbatCtrl BIT_4 
#define bitVddCtrl  BIT_14
```

However, when I run the code with the PModOLED attachment inserted into the JA header, it does not respond and the screen is blank. I would greatly appreciate it if you could tell me how to modify my code so that the PmodOLED add-on can be installed in the JA header.

Thanks in advance for your help, 
Guvvy